# Android MenuItem only showing in second load of fragment

Tags: android

I have a single activity android app, when the first fragment loads the toolbar doesn't show the `menuItem` but it does show the title. If I navigate to any other fragment, then back to the home fragment it works as expected.

I'm setting up the toolbar in the `MainActivity` as follows

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MenuHost {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        setupToolbar()
    }

    private fun setupToolbar() {
        val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val host =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment

        val navController = host.navController

        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.homeFragment))

        toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    }
}
```

Then in the HomeFragment I have something similar

```kotlin
private fun setupToolbar() {
    val mainActivity = requireActivity() as MainActivity
    val mainToolbar = mainActivity.findViewById<MaterialToolbar>(R.id.toolbar)

    // Clear previous menu items
    mainToolbar.menu.clear()

    // Set up toolbar
    mainToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.top_app_bar)
    mainToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener { menuItem ->
        when (menuItem.itemId) {
            R.id.more -> {
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_to_preferenceFragment)
            }
        }

        false
    }
}
```

Where this is being called in both `onViewCreated` and `onResume`.

where have I gone wrong here with getting the menu items showing up in the first load of the `HomeFragement`?

*Edit:* By adding these two methods on the fragment it solves my issue

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.top_app_bar, menu)
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
}
```

However they're apparently deprecated and reading the deprecation description they shouldn't be required as I'm using the `MenuHost` but perhaps I'm doing that wrong?